# GSON - serializing/deserializing subclasses that extend date?

Tags: java, json, gson

I am using gson to serialize/deserialize my objects to JSON (and vise versa). I currently have a class SpecificDate that extends Date. The problem is, when trying to deserialize SpecificDate, it doesn't seem to include the data in Date. This causes it to use the current date and time when serializing.

In the code, I create a specific date like the following -
`SpecificDate date = new SpecificDate(1592337581L)` Then serialize it to JSON and then deserialize it back to an object. Instead of the date being "2020-06-16T12:59:41.541" which was the date long supplied above, it instead returns the time it was created, so if it was created today, it would be something like this: 2020-08-11T12:51:44.542.

When serializing SpecificDate, the JSON ends up being the following -

```
{
 "SpecificDate" : {  
   "fieldInSpecificDate" : "value"
 }
}
```

How do I configure gson to serialize and deserialize so that SpecificDate will be serialized correctly?

---

Here's how each class looks

### SpecificDate

```
    public class SpecificDate extends Date {
    int specificDateVal = 0;
    //Constructor
    public SpecificDate (long date){
        super(date);
    }
}
```

### Main class

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Gson gs = new Gson();

        SpecificDate date = new SpecificDate(1597210221L);

        System.out.println("This is the date : " + date);

        String tester = gs.toJson(date);

        System.out.println("This is the JSON after deserialization : \n" + tester);

        Date deserialized = gs.fromJson(tester, SpecificDate.class);

        System.out.println("This is date after serialization : " + deserialized);
    }
}
```

### Output

```
This is the date : Mon Jan 19 03:40:10 PST 1970
This is the JSON after deserialization : 
{"specificDateVal":0}
This is date after serialization : Wed Dec 31 16:00:00 PST 1969
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you extend Date? And which Java version are you using?

Comment: I am using Java 1.8. For context, creating a web service for legacy code.

Comment: Have you considered using the classes in [the java.time package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)? I believe it is rather unusual having to extend Date, but I don't know enough about the problem you are trying to solve, so I might be wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't touch SpecificDate. The serialization/deserialization, is this a problem with the Date class?

Comment: I guess Date objects are automatically serialized to or deserialized from JSON numbers or strings (depending on the Gson configuration), so I think it is not a problem with the Date class. Have you tried creating a [custom serializer/deserializer](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization)?

Comment: I have, but I haven't come up with a working solution.